# Scrollspy doesn't work for the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and the scrollspy. 
I have a fixed to top navbar with affix.

The scrollspy is working correct but whenever i'm at the top of the site and no affix is active  and i click then on another menu item the offset is totally off. After that the site scrolls to the right menu items with correct offset. Just not whenever i click away from the first nav item. How come? I used

Html:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".mainnav">
```

And in the navigation id's

JS:

```
$('#nav').affix({
    offset: {
        top:  $('#nav').offset().top
    }
});

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Where could be the problem that the first click on a menu item after beginning at the top of the site is always wrong with the offset??

Comment: create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: That's sadly not that easy since i've already included all the external js, less and css ... not any awesome brainwave? :(

Comment: Usually it's because it was implemented incorrectly. The mistake people make most often is that they have ids in their header that don't mirror a # in their menu. If your scrollspy is the body, then all ids must marry up with a menu item. The other is that it's not the correct offset, try changing the value 10px-20px up or down